# Capturing WIM process hangs in MDT Litetouch

Tags: hyper-v, sysprep, mdt-2013

I'm trying to capture a WIM of my reference machine.  I setup a Sysprep and Capture task in MDT, ran it and used the default UNC path which is in the captures directory of my deployment share. The task will execute and initiate the LTI capture process.  The system restarts, boots into LTI, and begins capturing but the process hangs at the "Running action: Create WIM" step.  It usually hangs at 2.0% but I've seen it reach anywhere between 1-6%.

When I check the captures directory, a .wim file was created, but it's <100MB.  I've let the process run over night with no additional progress so it's definitely just hanging.

My reference machine is a hyper-v VM hosted on a dedicated machine for building images, but separate from my MDT server.

Which logs can help me figure out why it would be hanging?

And as another option, is there any way I can change the UNC path to point to a local HDD on my hyper-v server that I can manually copy up to MDT later?  When I tried redirecting it to a local share on my hyper-v server, it said the UNC path couldn't be connected to.

Comment: If it helps I've seen this kind of behavior when the local drive is unusually full. If you can try expanding the disk on your reference machine image so it's under 50% full.

Comment: Right now my reference machine is only using ~10gb of it's 64GB capacity.  It's a very minimal image right now.  Just trying to test a couple of customizations with a light-weight image for simplicity.  My final image will probably sit closer to 50% of the drive but I'll keep this in mind.  Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever solve this @Residualfail ?  Have the same issue

Comment: The problem did go away about a week after posting, but I'm not sure why.  My best guess was a network-based security mechanism was kicking in partway through which was killing the file transfer but wouldn't time out properly.  Our network\info sec guys have many mechanisms.....none of which I had any control over.  They have caused issues in the past for me.  Figured this was just one more casualty.